# i want to update my record using findOneAndUpdate in node.js and mongodb. it update all record expect fullname

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, mongodb

This is my schema and update function, here it update all of record expect fullname.

```
var employeeSchema = new Schema({
  fullname: {
    type: String,
  },

  email: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
  },

  mobile: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
  },
});

function UpdateEmployee(req, res) {
  Employee.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: req.body._id },
    req.body,
    { new: true },
    (err, docs) => {
      if (!err) {
        res.json(docs);
        //res.redirect('employee/list');
      } else {
        res.json("Updation Error " + err);
      }
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you `console.log('req.body')` to help troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

Delete the key value pair from the update object

```
function UpdateEmployee(req, res) {
  let data = {...req.body};
  delete data['fullname'];
  Employee.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: data._id },
    data,
    { new: true },
    (err, docs) => {
      if (!err) {
        res.json(docs);
        //res.redirect('employee/list');
      } else {
        res.json("Updation Error " + err);
      }
    }
  );
}
```

OR with spread the fullname key

```
function UpdateEmployee(req, res) {
  const {fullname,...data}= req.body;
  Employee.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: data._id },
    data,
    { new: true },
    (err, docs) => {
      if (!err) {
        res.json(docs);
        //res.redirect('employee/list');
      } else {
        res.json("Updation Error " + err);
      }
    }
  );
}
```